# Error on transfering data from file.txt to a table in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to transfer data from a text file: file.txt to a table in a database.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$host="mysq44.000webhost.com"; // Host name
$user="a203563_user"; // Mysql username
$pass="123omr"; // Mysql password
$db_name="a2031563_global"; // Database name
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name
$file = "file.txt";

$sql=mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass");
if (!$sql) {
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}else{
mysql_select_db("$db_name");
$re="LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE $tbl_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',')";
$result = mysql_query("$re");
if (!$result) {
    die("Could not load. " . mysql_error());
}

}
?>
```

but this is message appears:

```
Could not load. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'table FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',')' at line 1
```

Can anyone give me some solution or some ideas?

Comment: increase readability & spell correction

Answer (score 0):

The word 'table' is a reserved word in MySQL, you can't call a table, 'table', you'll need to change the name of your table or use backticks ( ` ) around the table name. You also seem to have closing brackets, but no opening ones - you'll want to fix that up to make this work.

Just in case you need it, here is the full syntax for the LOAD INFILE command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'somefile.txt' INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3);
```

Comment: YOu are great, I will test then reply to u

Comment: Could not load. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version !!!
the problem in the host web !!

Comment: yes Mr Luke ! no there is other msg say not allowed with this mySQL!

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're not in a position to change the MySQL version, you won't be able to use this command, then. If the original issue is fixed you may choose to accept the answer as correct for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Your load infile statement have 3 issues:

1. table: is reserved word in MySQL, you need to change table name or inclose inside (``)
2. remove the extra bracket at end of statement
3. The CSV file where you are using to load the data from MUST by owned by MySQL, use command line below:

   ```
    chown mysql.mysql file.txt
   ```

   So in general you need to make your load infile statement like

   ```
    $re = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE `$tbl_name` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','";
   ```